# Cosine of a matrix, investigation on integer matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry

So I'm trying to investigate matrices when trig is involved.

Let $A \in Z$, where Z is integers, be a two by two matrix. In other words, this matrix is 2x2 and is an integer matrix. (Where all entires are integers).

Upon investigation, it's clear that if cos(A) yields an integer matrix, then $A^2=0$.

How might I prove this, or disprove this(if I'm incorrect).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It suffices to note that the eigenvalues of $\cos(A)$ will be transcendental whenever $A$ has a non-zero eigenvalue

Comment: @Omnomnomnom interesting. Thank you :)

Comment: You'll want to use [Niven's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem) along with Omnomnomnom's observation.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician thank you:)